# jquery replace text in multidimensional array

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have an array, a json response 'slImgList':

```
[
    [1, 19054, "<img src="http://example.com/images/0/19054.jpg"/>"],
    [2, 24269, "<img src="http://example.com/images/0/24269.jpg"/>"],
    [3, 38777, "<img src="http://example.com/images/0/38777.jpg"/>"]
]
```

How can i replace 'images/0' with 'images/5' ?
homeListLength is number of arrays.

```
for (var i = 0; i < homeListLength; i++) {
    slImgList[i][2].replace("images/0", "images/5")
}
```

i have also tried something like this, but it doesnt work.

for (var i = 0; i < homeListLength; i++) {

```
    for (var j = 0; j < homeListLength[i]; j++) {
        imagesList = slImgList[j][2].replace("images/0", "images/5")
    }
}
```

Comment: `homeListLength = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(homeListLength).replace('/0/','/5/'));` -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/B9ZHt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it:

```
for (var j = 0; j < homeListLength[i]; j++) {
    imagesList = slImgList[j][2].replace("images/0", "images/5")
    slImgList[j][2] = imagesList
}
```